# What is the meaning of Tasks and Running in htop screen?

Tags: process, cpu, htop

On my computer it shows

```
Tasks 314; 24 running
```

What do these numbers mean?

Is 1 Task = 1 process?

Why isn't the number of running tasks = number of CPUs then? (I have more than 24 CPUs)

edit. sometimes the number before "running" actually exceeds the number of CPUs I have!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tasks do represent the number of opened processes.  (Note that I do not use the term "running" to avoid confusion.)

You have to realize that not all opened processes consume CPU constantly.

Each process can be in a number of different states:

- running:  actively using CPU
- stopped:  the process was stopped (paused) by the user
- defunc or zombie:  process is actually blocking on an external resource, commonly a disk drive
- sleeping:  most common state as many processes actually sleep a lot of the time and do small checks at different intervals, or wait for user input

Comment: thanks, why would #running processes be > #CPUs at times?

Comment: `htop` does an average which is how it shows a percentage of CPU usage.  Processes do not necessarily consume 100% of a CPU (or core).  This is managed by a scheduler within the kernel, one of the most complex parts of the kernel actually.  It ensures that all processes get a share of the CPU according to their priority compared to other processes.

Comment: If your server's load goes beyond 2 * numberOfCores, it most likely will become very unresponsive.  This is the kind of thing a good system admin will monitor.  The number of running processes is not that useful.

Answer (score 1):

A process is a running instance of a program. The numbers mean that 24 tasks are receiving inputs from the terminal while the rest are running in the background.

There is a very good post here:

http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/single-core-processor-run-multiple-tasks/

Also here to learn more about linux processes:

http://www.linfo.org/process.html